# PHP Last-Modified header not sent?

Tags: php, http-headers, last-modified

So I have this at the very top of my PHP file:

```
<?php
// Set headers
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Style-Type: text/css');
header('Content-Script-Type: application/javascript');
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
header('Content-language: en-US');
header('X-Powered-By: ');
header_remove('X-Powered-By');
header('Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT');
?>
```

So when I check the Firefox console's NET tab on my site's URL I don't see the Last-Modified header. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post the header response?

Comment: Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/MP3RCZW.png

Comment: To be fair, you're telling the browser to cache nothing and he MUST revalidate everything. So the last-modified header doesn't matter.

Comment: Ooh now I got it! How dumb am I! Thanks! post this as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Make sure you don't have "Header unset Last-Modified" in your .htaccess file

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You're telling the browser to cache nothing and he MUST revalidate everything. So the last-modified header doesn't matter.

Comment: -1 It doesn't matter if the browser MUST revalidate the resources. I got here researching how to get that header even if the HTML has a no-cache policy, because I use it in AJAX requests. Still no luck though.